# How to access F# module under Interactive mode in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, f#, f#-interactive

I have a mid-sized project featured with many modules and dependencies.  The whole project
compiles well under Visual Studio. But now I would like to access
some modules in the project under interactive mode. As an artificial
example, I have

```
open B
module A

let foo x = goo(x)+1
```

where goo is from the module B.

I would like to have interactively
play with A.x. But if I only select that function definition and use
VS's "send selected part to F# interactive", I will not have the
dependencies. What should I do to have an interactive F# window from
which I can access A.x with its dependencies also available?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the example you showed, run `open B` in F# interactive, then you'll have access to what is defined in module B.